# Issue around utc date - TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc results in date change

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, utc

Having an issue whereby the date I wish to save is changing from the onscreen selected date if the users selects a timezone that is ahead x number of hours.
E.g. they choose *UTC+2 Athens* and date of `25/02/2016` from the calendar pop-up, then date recorded will be `24/02/2016`.
I've narrowed the reasoning down to the fact that the selected datetime is recorded as for example `25/02/2016 00:00:00` and with the 2 hour offset, this takes it to `24/02/2016 22:00:00`
Having never worked with timezones before, or UTC dates/times, this is highly confusing.

**Here is the code -**

```
     oObject.RefDate = itTimeAndDate.ParseDateAndTimeNoUTCMap(Request, TextBox_RefDate.Text);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oObject.TimeZoneDetails))
        {
TimeZoneInfo oTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(oObject.TimeZoneDetails);
            oObject.RefDate = itTimeAndDate.GetUTCUsingTimeZone(oTimeZone, oObject.RefDate);  
        }
```

`RefDate` would equate to something like `25/02/2016 00:00:00` once returned from `ParseDateAndTimeNoUTCMap` * (code below)*

```
static public itDateTime ParseDateAndTimeNoUTCMap(HttpRequest oTheRequest, string sValue)
        {
            DateTime? oResult = ParseDateAndTimeNoUTCMapNull(oTheRequest, sValue);
            if (oResult != null)
                return new itDateTime(oResult.Value);
            return null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Translate a string that has been entered by a user to a UTC date / time - mapping using the
        /// current time zone
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="oTheRequest">Request context</param>
        /// <param name="sValue">Date / time string entered by a user</param>
        /// <returns>UTC date / time object</returns>
        static public DateTime? ParseDateAndTimeNoUTCMapNull(HttpRequest oTheRequest, string sValue)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sValue))
                    return null;
                sValue = sValue.Trim();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sValue))
                    return null;

                if (oTheRequest != null)
                {
                    const DateTimeStyles iStyles = DateTimeStyles.AllowInnerWhite | DateTimeStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | DateTimeStyles.AllowTrailingWhite;
                    // Create array of CultureInfo objects
                    CultureInfo[] aCultures = new CultureInfo[oTheRequest.UserLanguages.Length + 1];
                    for (int iCount = oTheRequest.UserLanguages.GetLowerBound(0); iCount <= oTheRequest.UserLanguages.GetUpperBound(0);
                         iCount++)
                    {
                        string sLocale = oTheRequest.UserLanguages[iCount];
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sLocale))
                        {

                            // Remove quality specifier, if present.
                            if (sLocale.Contains(";"))
                                sLocale = sLocale.Substring(0, sLocale.IndexOf(';'));
                            try
                            {
                                aCultures[iCount] = new CultureInfo(sLocale, false);
                            }
                            catch (Exception) { }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            aCultures[iCount] = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                        }
                    }
                    aCultures[oTheRequest.UserLanguages.Length] = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                    // Parse input using each culture.
                    foreach (CultureInfo culture in aCultures)
                    {
                        DateTime oInputDate;
                        if (DateTime.TryParse(sValue, culture.DateTimeFormat, iStyles, out oInputDate))
                            return oInputDate;
                    }
                }
                return DateTime.Parse(sValue);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Once returned from the above, the following lines are executed -

```
TimeZoneInfo oTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(oObject.TimeZoneDetails);
        oObject.RefDate = itTimeAndDate.GetUTCUsingTimeZone(oTimeZone, oObject.RefDate);
```

It is within `GetUTCUsingTimeZone` that the problem seems to occur to me.

```
static public itDateTime GetUTCUsingTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo oTimeZone, itDateTime oDateTime)
    {
        if (oDateTime == null || oTimeZone == null)
         return oDateTime;
         DateTime oLocal = DateTime.SpecifyKind(oDateTime.Value, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
        DateTime oResult = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(oLocal, oTimeZone);

        return new itDateTime(oResult);
    }
```

I have checked `TimezoneInfo` for the offset value, and `oResult` always equates to the `oLocal param` - the offset. So `25/02/2016 00:00:00` with a 3 hour offset would equate to `24/02/2016 21:00:00`
When the offset is -hours, it goes in the other direct, so o`Result = oLocal + the offset`, if that makes sense. So the main issue of the date changing is not occurring in those instances.

Obviously this is not what I want. I want the date to be what the user has selected, for their timezone.
Has anyone seen something like this before? Any possible solution?

I'm not entirely sure what I've done wrong.

Comment: What does the `itTimeAndDate` struct/class look like?

Comment: @Ian Kemp - managed to resolve this issue by doing a ConvertTimeFromUtc operation on the data the user enters (after it has had the ConvertTimeToUtc operation performed and saved to the db) when a user returns to this page.
So the page displays the date the user selected, and whats recorded in the db is the local equivalent of what they selected, if that makes sense.
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Unclear. A Date doesn't really have a TimeZone... A DateTime value does. What kind of UI component(s) do you use, what is the intended use of including a TZ?

Comment: So if you managed to fix it and the fix is not useful for others, feel free to delete the question

Comment: Apologies -I've added the fix to the main question

Comment: You should "answer your own question" if you found an answer... (i.e. add an answer yourself)

Comment: Triple double triple second @rogerdpack's comment - though many people do it (and they **shouldn't**), putting the answer into the question is bad practice and *discouraged*.  Self-answers, on the other hand, are *encouraged* so please put the answer as an *answer*.

Comment: Normally, I find the "You should use X" comments quite annoying, but having written a lot of DateTime-handling code in C#, I've found NodaTime to be incredibly useful. It might be worth a look. -- http://nodatime.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you need to maintain the correct timezone, you should be using the `DateTimeOffset` type instead of `DateTime` type.

`DateTimeOffset` maintains the offset from UTC so you never lose your timezone information and has a lot of useful methods like
`UtcDateTime`

From the horses mouth:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to run the following after grabbing the value from the db and before redisplaying it -

```
static public itDateTime FixUTCUsingTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo oTimeZone, itDateTime oDateTime)
{
    if (oDateTime == null || oTimeZone == null)
        return oDateTime;

    DateTime oTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(oDateTime.Value, DateTimeKind.Unspecified);
    DateTime oResult = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(oTime, oTimeZone);

    return new itDateTime(oResult);
```

}

So essentially just doing the reverse of the ConvertTimeToUtc performed earlier. Not sure why this wasn't done originally, but there you go.